# toggle class for toggling subscription box jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a toggling div for a subscription box. I am styling it so it is flush on the bottom, and has a negative margin to hide all but the top. What I want to do is toggle the class of the parent div with an onclick event, I'm not sure of the issue I am having, i did have a few bugs which i think I've managed to work out but im obviously missing something as it isn't working. I'm not sure what exactly unfortunately. Here's the code:

JS:

```
var subscribe = document.getElementById('subscribe');
subscribe.style.cursor = 'pointer';
subscribe.onclick (function raise(){
  if (subscribe.hasClass('subscription') === true) {
    subscribe.toggleClass('raised', 800);
  } else {
   subscribe.toggleClass('subscription', 800);
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="subscription" id="subscribe" onclick="raise()">
 <div class="sub-tab">
   + keep in touch
   </div>
   <div class="sub-body">
     Subscribe to our newsletter to get our latest offers and news.
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.subscription {
  height: 400px;
  width: 350px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -365px;
}
.raise {
  height: 400px;
  width: 350px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I should probably add that I'm getting the error that raise is undefined, though isnt the `function raise()` part defining it?

Comment: @Cygwinnian http://jsfiddle.net/Htunj/

Comment: It's worth noting that your classes aren't the same (.raise [css] and .raised [js]).

Comment: @shirejedi that is true, we caught that in the answer down below, but great catch. Unfortunately it wasn't the source of the problem but it would of been if we didn't catch it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `subscribe.onclick` via javascript as well as inline... the `raise` method is defined inside the onclick function so won't be visible in scope to the html

Take out the `onclick="raise()"`

and change the event to:

`subscribe.on('click', function(){`

Because you're using jQuery, you don't need `getElementById`:

```
$('#subscribe')
```

Also, `=== true` is redundant:

```
if (subscribe.hasClass('subscription')) {
```

will suffice

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but didn't work, here's a jsfiddle of the changes i made, maybe I missed something:

http://jsfiddle.net/Htunj/2/

Comment: You were using `raised` in the css and `raise` in the javascript. You still had `margin-bottom: -345px` for the `raised` class. Changing those, as well as how you set the `css` via javascript solves it: http://jsfiddle.net/Htunj/3/

Comment: Also, the `toggleClass` method doesn't take a number for its second argument. You may be looking for `animate` https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/‎

Comment: ok, i believe the addClass and removeClass methods do, so I assumed toggleClass did as well, i can tackle the speed aspect later. I fixed the css calling raised instead of raise and removed `=== true` but it is still not working. It also isn't adjusting the mouse to be a pointer either, here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Htunj/4/

Comment: Because the mouse isn't adjusting I'm guessing `var subscribe = $('#subscribe');` isn't working

Comment: in the console im getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cursor' of undefined `

Comment: Did you look at the code in my fiddle? I fixed everything I advised, include the `style.cursor` errors

Comment: I missed the fiddle, i'm looking at it now

Comment: Oh, ok, awesome. So it looks like even though we were changing the class to one that didn't have a negative margin that because we weren't setting it to 0 it stayed at `-345px` is that right?

Comment: Correct, you need to override previous styles otherwise they'll still apply. Unless you're removing the original class entirely which currently you're not. It would super easy to put the css into an `animate` function and have is slide up.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was originally going to animate the transition from a negative margin to no margin, but it became complex when i tried to toggle it, so i went this route. I probably should of just figured out the toggle aspect. Thanks!